# Ionic2 - Push new page inside <div>

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to push new pages inside the current page's `<div>` element. I have tried various methods found on SO but nothing worked for me. I have this code right now which doesn't work.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div #pageView>
  </div>
</ion-content>

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class Vehiclemaintenance {

    @ViewChild('pageView') nav: NavController

    Constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

    loadPage(){
        this.nav.push(myComponent)
    }

}
```

This causes an error

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.nav.push is not a function
```

Where am I going wrong!

*** Update that worked ***

Instead of using a `<div>` element I used `<ion-nav>`

Comment: That's not something you can do in Ionic. If you want to reuse some parts of the view, create a custom component with that code, and then add it to the view/s using its component selector like `<app-custom-component></app-custom-component>`

Comment: I got this working! Check my update